# Large white space under image, using percentage sizing so image fills screen on all viewing platforms

Tags: html, css, image

I am building a site that depends on the image being large on the screen, so I have chosen to use percentages to control the size.  The problem I am trying to deal with is the white space that always appears under the image.  I have tried out a lot of the suggestions but nothing works.  Is it because the original image is larger than the image viewed (sized down by the percentage)? Should I somehow get rid of the vertical scrollbar?
Help would be much appreciated

here is a link to a page I am working on

http://www.michael-simpson.co.uk/New%20Site/BenchPaintingsPages/BenchPainting74.html

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I think the height 100vw for your rightcolumn class could be the problem

Comment: That has solved the problem!! Thank you SO much. I was getting sick with frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your height on your right column is not in px.

```
.RightColumn {
      height: 100vw;
}
```

Change it to:

```
.RightColumn {
      height: 100px;
}
```

A good way to examine problems when you are not sure what the issue is, is to use the browser HTML examiner (Ctrl + Shift + C in Chrome). It will show you each rule being applied and allow you to change/turn them off to see what happens dynamically. In this case, your RightColumn class was stretching to 1900+ px in height.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have changed the height to 100% rather than px as I need to keep everything in proportion as it sizes. Also thanks for the tip about HTML examiner, that will be very helpful.

Comment: Glad to help. Please remember to accept an answer if you feel it properly answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

the white space is caused because of this div with class `RightColumn` reduce the height and the problem will be fixed like so :

```
  .RightColumn {

      height: 19vw;
}
```

or

```
.RightColumn {

          height: 100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the height 100vw for your rightcolumn class could be the problem

You can use debug tools like firebug or developer tools which are available on all the browsers :)